# How to go from $\sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}\theta}=A$ to $V=A\cdot \ln(\tan\frac{\theta}{2}) +B$ by integration?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, reduction-formula

This problem originally stems from a practice problem from my electromagnetism course, but the actual problem is not relevant for my question.

**Problem**

We were asked to find to solve the following LaPlace's equation with respect to $V$ (electric potential).

$$\frac{1}{R^2\sin(\theta)} \cdot \frac{d}{d\theta} \bigg(\sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{dV}{d\theta} \bigg) = 0 $$

**My instructor's solution**

My instructor provided us with his solution where he solves LaPlace'
s equation like this:

[image]

**My question**

How does he go from $\sin(\theta) \frac{dV}{d\theta}=A$ to $V(\theta)=A\ln\big(\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})\big)+B$ ?

I think it something to do with dividing with $\sin(\theta)$ on both sides and then integrating with respect to $\theta$, but when I do it I get this result:
$$V(\theta)=A\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\bigg) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is same -

$V(\theta)=A\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\bigg)$

Now please note that

$\cos \theta = \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}$

and $\sin \theta = 2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}$

So, $\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}} = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$

So, $V(\theta)=A\ln\bigg(\tan \frac{\theta}{2}\bigg) + B \,$ where $B$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{multline}
\int\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta}=\int\frac{2dz}{\sin2z}=\int\frac{\sin^2z+\cos^2z}{\sin z\cos z}dz=\int\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}dz+\int\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}dz\\=-\int\frac{du}{u}+\int\frac{dv}{v}=\ln\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)=\ln\tan\frac{\theta}{2}
\end{multline}

where $z=\theta/2$, $u=\cos z$, $v=\sin z$.